# Expand Items to max text length in Selectric Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a menu using jQuery and Selectric frameworks and I have run in to a problem that I need some help with. With this menu, I want to have the min width of the dropdown be the max-width of the largest text item in the drop down select.

As it is now, I can have max and min widths preset, but I would like to have min width be the max width of the longest item. Thanks for the help in advanced

Here's the code I am using: http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/

Comment: I have tried to set the label length to the "expandOnHover" list length to make the final length of the dropdown menu consistent. If you add a really long item to the select in the html, it will expand to fit in the drop down, but I want to to ALWAYS be the same size as the largest item, both in the drop down, and when it's not selected.

Comment: have you tried to set `expandToItemText: true;` ?

Comment: yes, That just expands the drop down part of the menu to the longest value, then when I select something with a small value, it contracts

Answer (score 2):

Although it's a little bit late, you may want to try the `inheritOriginalWidth` property:

```
$('select').selectric({
    inheritOriginalWidth: true
});
```

This will automatically make your selectric dropdown the same width as your original `<select>` element, and it won't change responsively when you select a new option.

Obviously if you have padding, margins, dropdown arrow button etc. on your custom selectric box, you'll need to CSS styling accordingly to make sure everything is visible, as `inheritOriginalWidth` won't account for these things.

Comment: Beware of that this fails (as of v1.9.0) if element or it's parent is hidden from the DOM by `display:none` https://github.com/lcdsantos/jQuery-Selectric/issues/87

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I thought I was never going to be able to fix it.

Comment: @RobIsAnxious No problem! I remember it taking me a while to figure out myself -_-